Unhandled 64-bit el1h sync exception for HVC instruction on ARMv9 QEMU simulation
I encountered this error while trying to bring up the Jailhouse hypervisor on an ARMv9 chipset. HVC instruction was not handled properly and the kernel reports error message as follows:
root@demo:~# insmod lkm_example.ko  
[  327.255634] Unhandled 64-bit el1h sync exception on CPU14, ESR 0x000000005a000000 -- HVC (AArch64)
[  327.256000] CPU: 14 PID: 460 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           O       6.1.90 #4
[  327.256279] Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
[  327.256534] pstate: 60400009 (nZCv daif +PAN -UAO -TCO -DIT -SSBS BTYPE=--)
[  327.256690] pc : lkm_example_init+0x1c/0x1000 [lkm_example]
[  327.257597] lr : lkm_example_init+0x18/0x1000 [lkm_example]
[  327.257721] sp : ffff8000089d3b20
[  327.257775] x29: ffff8000089d3b20 x28: 0000000000000000 x27: ffff8000089d3ce0
[  327.258831] x26: ffff8000089d3c90 x25: ffff8000089d3ce0 x24: ffffcaae92306e58
[  327.259153] x23: ffffcaae4e356058 x22: 0000000000000000 x21: ffff5f40048d0ec0
[  327.259442] x20: ffffcaae4e359000 x19: ffffcaae9261b000 x18: 0000000000000020
[  327.259784] x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffcaae9119792c x15: fffffffffffe6550
[  327.260083] x14: 0000000000000002 x13: ffffcaae92293398 x12: 00000000000004a7
[  327.260287] x11: 000000000000018d x10: ffffcaae922eb398 x9 : ffffcaae92293398
[  327.260522] x8 : 00000000ffffefff x7 : ffffcaae922eb398 x6 : 0000000000000000
[  327.260743] x5 : ffff5f402d1d8a18 x4 : ffff5f402d1d8a18 x3 : 0000000000000000
[  327.260958] x2 : 0000000000000000 x1 : ffff5f40048d0ec0 x0 : 000000000000000e
[  327.261406] Kernel panic - not syncing: Unhandled exception
[  327.261554] CPU: 14 PID: 460 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           O       6.1.90 #4
[  327.261684] Hardware name: linux,dummy-virt (DT)
[  327.261809] Call trace:
[  327.261999]  dump_backtrace.part.0+0xdc/0xf0
[  327.262743]  show_stack+0x18/0x30
[  327.262855]  dump_stack_lvl+0x68/0x84
[  327.262951]  dump_stack+0x18/0x34
[  327.263041]  panic+0x184/0x34c
[  327.263134]  arm64_exit_nmi.isra.0+0x0/0x80
[  327.263228]  el1h_64_sync_handler+0x6c/0xe4
[  327.263341]  el1h_64_sync+0x64/0x68
[  327.263480]  lkm_example_init+0x1c/0x1000 [lkm_example]
[  327.263667]  do_one_initcall+0x50/0x1d0
[  327.263758]  do_init_module+0x48/0x1d0
[  327.263850]  load_module+0x18e8/0x1c70
[  327.263939]  __do_sys_finit_module+0xa8/0x100
[  327.264032]  __arm64_sys_finit_module+0x20/0x30
[  327.264131]  invoke_syscall+0x48/0x120
[  327.264226]  el0_svc_common.constprop.0+0x44/0xf4
[  327.264318]  do_el0_svc+0x30/0xd0
[  327.264408]  el0_svc+0x2c/0x84
[  327.264498]  el0t_64_sync_handler+0xbc/0x140
[  327.264589]  el0t_64_sync+0x18c/0x190
[  327.265192] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[  327.265959] Kernel Offset: 0x4aae88200000 from 0xffff800008000000
[  327.266031] PHYS_OFFSET: 0xffffa0c040000000
[  327.266093] CPU features: 0x00040,000f00b7,665276af
[  327.266242] Memory Limit: 768 MB
[  327.298676] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Unhandled exception ]---

But oddly If I simulate the chipset as ARMv8 then everything went well, that is to say
qemu-system-aarch64 ... -cpu cortex-a53 ... [All good]
qemu-system-aarch64 ... -cpu cortex-a710 ...[HVC instruction not handled]

So I suspect this is an ARM issue. What should I do or check to fix this issue? Here is the code snippet I tested with:
static int __init lkm_example_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, World!!\n");

#if 1
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "hvc #0"  // hvc instruction
        :
        :
        :
    );
#endif
    return 0;
}

static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, World!\n");
}

module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);

I think the hvc instruction should be handled in kernel arch/arm64/kernel/hyp-stub.S.
PS. I'm using Linux kernel v6.1.90, QEMU 9.2.0.
